# WPF Setting Image.Source from DataTrigger

Tags: wpf, image, styles, datatrigger

I'm trying to define a `DataTrigger` for an `Image` element so that it shows a connected/disconnected image. I keep getting an `Invalid PropertyDescriptor` message. Any ideas?

```
<Image>
    <Image.Style>
      <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static my:Server.Instance}, Path=Connected, Mode=OneWay}"
                       Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Source"
                    Value="serverconnected.png"/>
          </DataTrigger>

        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 8):

I just changed Property="Source" to Property="Image.Source" and it's working. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

Add a BitmapImage to your resources like so:

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="serverConnected" UriSource="serverconnected.png" />
```

And change your existing code to refer to it:

```
<Image>
<Image.Style>
  <Style>
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static my:Server.Instance}, Path=Connected, Mode=OneWay}"
                   Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Source"
                Value="{StaticResource serverConnected}"/>
      </DataTrigger>

    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</Image.Style>
```

Comment: This was a nice suggestion but was not the solution to the problem. +1 for the quick reply!